# Error using ScraperAPI With Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I can't figure out where the error is in this code. Basically it inserts a code in the search bar, clicks a button and extracts the results:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time

API_KEY = 'my_api_key'

proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'https': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

url =  'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

vats = ['06655971007', '05779661007', '08526440154']

for vat in vats:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(5)

    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//input[@id="search_input"]')
    item.send_keys(vat)

    time.sleep(1)

    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//p//button[@type="submit"]')
    button.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')
    for item in all_items:
        if '@' in item.text:
            print(item.text.split(' ')[1])

driver.close()
```

Running the script (chromedriver.exe is saved in the same folder and I'm working in Jupyter Notebook, if it matters) I get

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//input[@id="search_input"]"}
```

but this element exists, because trying the script without ScraperAPI I get no errors. Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here you are running with a loop for 3 `vat` values.
   After the first click on the search button the result page is presented.
   There is no search input field and search button there!
   So, in order to perform a new search you need to get back to the previous page after getting the data on the result page.
2. There is no need to create a new instance of web driver each iteration.
3. Also, you should use Expected Conditions explicit waits instead of hardcoded pauses.
   This should work better:

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

API_KEY = 'my_api_key'

proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'https': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

url =  'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

vats = ['06655971007', '05779661007', '08526440154']



driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)


for vat in vats:
    input_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//input[@id="search_input"]')))
    input_search.clear()
    input_search.send_keys(vat)

    time.sleep(0.5)

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//p//button[@type="submit"]'))).click()

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')))

    time.sleep(0.5)

    all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')
    for item in all_items:
        if '@' in item.text:
            print(item.text.split(' ')[1])
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

driver.close()
```

**UPD**
This code is working, the output is

> enelenergia@pec.enel.it
> info@pec.terna.it
> edisonenergia@pec.edison.it

Comment: It doesn't work. I get `TimeoutException` on the first line inside the for loop.

Comment: Right, I just tried that. We cannot click submit button there instantly after inserting the search text. Also, the search input should be cleaned before inserting new texts. Please see the updated code, I tested it, it works correctly.

Comment: I get again `TimeoutException` on the line `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')))`. If the code we launch is the same, what can be the difference?

Comment: Does submit button got clicked and the result is displayed after that when you run it? On my side the answer is yes.

Comment: In the browser screen that opens at the end I find "Request failed. You will not be charged for this request. Please make sure your url is correct and try the request again. If this continues to happen, please contact support@scraperapi.com.".

Comment: well, this is because you are using proxies. My code running without it.

Comment: I have disabled proxies from the Settings section of the browser, but it still doesn't work. Is it normal that it takes a long time to load the page, enter the code, etc.? Anyway I followed the process: he inserts the code and after a while the error I reported above appears. Could there be a reCAPTCHA?

Comment: Maybe they detected too many requests from your IP address? I run my code maybe 10 times or more - no captchas etc. appeared. Worked perfectly

Comment: But shouldn't using ScraperAPI solve the problem of too many requests from a single IP address? How long does it take for your code to run?

Comment: I never used ScraperAPI, so I don't know. Each run took maybe 20-30 seconds. But I tried it again now - it doesn't work. Looks like that site detected abnormal activity...

Comment: I see. If you've never used Scraper API, which API_KEY did you use?

Comment: None :) Why should I use them? For what? I have 8+ years experience working with Selenium but never needed them.

Comment: So you ran the code without the variables `API_KEY` and `proxy_options`, and not putting parameters in `webdriver.Chrome()`. Is it correct? I have tried and it works, only I think after some trying I will be blocked from the site.

Comment: Yes, that exactly is what I did.

Comment: I think your original question was not about the proxies and the API_KEYs. I understand these are things causing problems now, but as I feel I have answered your original question itself.

Comment: Yes, I accepted your answer, very helpful, thank you. Just one last question: did you use `from selenium import webdriver` or `from seleniumwire import webdriver`?

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver` I never used `seleniumwire`. Even don't actually know what is it ;)

Comment: Another question arose about your solution: it makes sense to add more `time.sleep()`, perhaps between the two `wait.until()` (or increase the time in the ones that are already there) to decrease the risk of errors in code execution?

Comment: I think this will have no sense. As I feel there is some kind of JS on the page that activated by clicking on elements so that you can not click immediately after that on another element until some process on the page is completed. That's why we need a short delays there. But since it's something inside the page, not dealing with the server side responses increasing the delays wil not help here.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes, after a single vat process is finished, I get ERR_CACHE_MISS on the Chrome page. Does it make sense to put `webdriver.refresh()` at the end of the loop?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry. When I run my code I didn't met this error.